# How to create a Filter Form using simple form rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to know how to create a form (using simple forms) that generate me a query based when i click on subbit button. Because a i have a model called Houses and my index show me all houses, i need to create a filter of this houses like filter by house location. actually i already crete the filter mechanism if i put ur like /houses&country=COUTRY it will show me only houses of this country.

here is my code:

**house.rb:**

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
    has_many :watches
    scope :status, -> (status) { where status: status }
    scope :country, -> (country) { where country: country }
   end
```

**house_controller: (only important parts)**

```
def index
    @houses = House.all
    filtering_params(params).each do |key, value|
    @houses = @houses.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
end

def filtering_params(params)
    params.slice(:status, :country)
end
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: I think it is a mistake to try to leverage your House ActiveRecord model for this purpose.  Your form is going to generate a query, not save data to the database.  A better approach would be to create a 'form object' to handle this task.  The 'virtus' gem can be included in that class to assist with any typecasting you may need.  See e.g. http://webuild.envato.com/blog/creating-form-objects-with-activemodel-and-virtus/

Comment: thank you, but i don't tryng to store anything database i want just do user filter the data in index view, the query works fine but i need a form to user dont need to type the query by hand